# SQL Error "Argument not specified for parameter " Adding this Fillby3 has caused issues and I'm not really proficient in SQL. Any suggestions?

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Public Shared Sub getfilterValues(ByVal Type As Integer, ByVal value As String, ByVal gold As Boolean)
    Try
        Select Case Type

            Case 0
                Form1.tTimeTableAdapter.FillBy(Form1.DataSet1.tTime, value)
            Case 1
                Form1.tTimeTableAdapter.FillBy1(Form1.DataSet1.tTime, value)
            Case 2
                Form1.tTimeTableAdapter.FillBy2(Form1.DataSet1.tTime, value)
            Case 3
                Form1.tTimeTableAdapter.FillBy3(Form1.DataSet1.tTime, value)
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Form1.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

Error thrown by `FillBy3` in case 3:

> Argument not specified for parameter ’Date1’ of ‘Public Overridable Overloads Function Fillby3(dataTable as DataSet1.tTimeDataTable,tDate as Date?,tDate1 as Date?”) as integer’.

Comment: Well, SQL is not really an issue here and quite irrelevant to the problem.  It's simply you're calling a method that takes 3 parameters and only supplied 2

Comment: This is off-topic but you should absolutely NOT have methods named `FillBy`, `FillBy1`, etc. EVERYTHING you use should have a descriptive name. The idea with table adapters is that the default query, i.e. `SELECT *` without a `WHERE`, is executed when you call `Fill` or `GetData` and any methods you add to execute other queries should describe those queries. For instance, if you add a query `SELECT * FROM Child WHERE ParentId = ?` then you would name the corresponding methods `FillByParentId` and `GetDataByParentId`. We should know what the method does from it's name.

Comment: Also, using magic numbers is always bad. You're a beginner so it is understandable that you didn't know but that `Type` parameter should be of an `Enum` type so each label is self-documenting. The numbers 0 to 3 mean nothing to us in that code and will mean nothing to you in a few months if you put that code away and come back to it. The `Enum` field labels and the `FillByX` method names should all correspond, e.g. `QueryFilterColumn.ParentId` and `FillByParentId`.

Comment: Thanks Hursey and jm for your input. I know  the wisdom of naming conventions which was not followed in an online video to produce reports in vs2015. Thus, the newbee in me did not see that it is important in this area. Thanks Again!! I have to shelve this project for a few days, but will let you know the results.